# How to Change the Parameter Value in JMeter "Http Request" for a checkbox with "title" text controlling the state

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I have a checkbox in the DOM rendered as:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" title="Select all rows in this table">
```

Now, when i "inspect" the page, the selection of the checkbox changes the input to:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox" title="Deselect all rows in this table">
```

In JMeter, I want to be able to send a POST request with Parameters ( Name, Value ) to change the title to "Deselect all rows in this table" but I am unable to figure out how to "Set" the value. Since using Regular Expression Extractor, I can only do the substitution as ${CBtitle}
if, let's say I have a Regex Extractor:
name of created variable: CBtitle

```
Regular Expression: class="form-checkbox" title="(.*)"
Template: $1$
Match No: 
Default Value:
```

So this Regex would be true and can be used as ${CBtitle}, BUT, how can we change the
value of title to "Deselect all rows in this table" making the checkbox, selected.

If I use the "Default Value" as "Deselect all rows in this table" it does show as:

CBtitle=Deselect all rows in this table

but, it does not seem to select the checkbox.

**Before Checkbox is selected:**

```
<input class="display-inline form-text usa-input" data-drupal-selector="edit-unit-id" 
aria-describedby="edit-unit-id--description" data-msg-maxlength="Establishment/Unit Number  
field has a maximum length of 128." type="text" id="edit-unit-id" name="unit_id" value="" 
size="60" maxlength="128" 
data-drupal-states="{&quot;disabled&quot;:{&quot;:input[name=\u0022id_check\u0022]&quot;:{&quot;checked&quot;:true}}}">
```

**After Checkbox is selected:**

```
<input class="display-inline form-text usa-input" data-drupal-selector="edit-unit-id" 
aria-describedby="edit-unit-id--description" data-msg-maxlength="Establishment/Unit Number  
field has a maximum length of 128." type="text" id="edit-unit-id" name="unit_id" 
value="" size="60" maxlength="128" 
data-drupal-states="{&quot;disabled&quot;:{&quot;:input[name=\u0022id_check\u0022]&quot;:{&quot;checked&quot;:true}}}" disabled="">
```

Comment: @Dmitri T Adding a Sample Checkbox Before and After state, in the question, since formatting for HTML is not available in comments. Can this be handled by JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter doesn't "check" the boxes as it happens solely on client side, neither it can manipulate [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)

If "clicking" the checkbox triggers a [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) - you can capture the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/)

If clicking the checkbox doesn't generate a HTTP Request - you won't be able to test it using JMeter, you will need a real browser for this so it's better to take a look at browser automation framework like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/). If you prefer to stay with JMeter there is [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin which provides JMeter integration with Selenium